# MySQL online import and export

Tags: mysql, database, import, export

I need to Export and Import MySQL database online, in order to transfer data from/ to a network. Currently I use this functionality with 'mysqldump' . But it has a limitation that if I import a database to existing database, the database get updated with new values from imported Database.

My current requirement is to export a database in source and import it to destination , provided the IP address or system name. And I am supposed to perform the import and export via INFILE and OUTFILE.

Edit :

In my application there are 3 options,

1. Export database - Export the database from application to the local system
2. Import database - Import the database from a file in local system to the database in application
3. Online interchange - Export database from the source and Import to the destination system.

The import and Export from and to local is implemented via INFILE and OUTFILE scenario. I wish to perform the Online interchange also with the same concept rather than mysdqldump.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Explain in more details of what exactly you want to achieve

Comment: @zerkms The question is edited now. Hope you get it.

Comment: It still doesn't clarify what exactly what you need to do. For **current** question the only answer is: does `INFILE` and `OUTFILE` solve your issue? If yes - then use them, if no - then don't.

Comment: If it still not clear for you what is vague in the question - you haven't explained what you have (how many servers and what servers). What data they store. What you need to do with data. Why you need that to do.

Comment: @zerkms can you specify what is unclear from the edited question?

Answer (score 0):

I think a better solution is to use [replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html). It would be safer.